# Ng-class return class name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new with angularjs, I would try to get the name of the CSS class of dynamic way. Is there a way to pass such as a string returned from my database?

example:

```
<div ng-class = "app.name.lastname"> </ div>
```

And he get the result like this:

```
<div class = "lastname"> </ div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is

```
 <div class = "{{name.lastname}}"> </ div>
```

Comment: Hey @Karthik, It worked ... thanks ! was trying {name.lastname} my mistake !

Comment: Sure! I'll do it now!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to utilize `ng-class` you better user either function of object.

```
<div ng-class="getClass(app.name.lastname)"> </ div>
<div ng-class="{'lastname': app.name.lastname}"> </ div>
```

On the other hand I noticed that you probably want give every DIV a class of object key. SO all divs with values of object key `lastname` has this class and all values of object key `firstname` has this class. There are few ways to do that. But I would like to see how you iterate through your object. Show more code.

Comment: Actually I have several names of background:
example:

back01, back02... Need to apply every background the name of the class que I use this result in new functionality That Is ... I know I'm in the home and I'm with the back01.

These background are saved Within hotel.backgroundImage.name;

One must return to the class and make a function using These names Simulated with names That Could return several. But I think it worked well. The problem is that in my home I have not crirei my hotel, and it do not have a controller. This way I will have to create a controller for home. It uses a ui-view